# How to multiply session value?

Tags: php

Hi does any one know how to I multiply a session variable x $1000 in PHP? 
can I do something like:

$_SESSION['ctables'] x $1000?

I am lost

Comment: How would you multiply *any* variable?

Comment: `x $1000`? look up "how to multiply in php".

Comment: `@ff cc` mark answers which helps you to solve your problem with correct and proper description.

Answer (score 3):

in simple way

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['ctables'] = $_SESSION['ctables'] * 1000;
```